# Python dictionary random key print

Tags: python, random, dictionary, printing

I have a Python dictionary containing pairs of words of the format German:English.
for example:
    dict {"eigentlich":"basically"}, e.t.c

Is there a way of enumerating the pairs, so that I can randomly print a key as a question to the user (using rand in a for loop?)?

Comment: What's wrong with taking the keys and shuffling?

Comment: @mskimm that's great! I didn't know that dict.items and dict.keys returned lists..!! The post you mentioned gives me a solution. Thanks

Comment: @alex777 -- Careful though.  They don't return `list` objects in python3.x.  There they return `view` objects and many of the `random` functions don't work with `view` objects.  When working with `random`, I would suggest `list(dictionary)` instead of `dictionary.keys()` for forward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to me that we could do a little better in terms of an answer here, so here's my attempt.

First we need to import the `random` module, as we'll be using the `choice` function from it on the list of dict keys:

```
import random
```

Next we need some data in a dict format, I pulled a translation from some website of one to ten from English to German and added it to our dict for demonstration purposes.

```
my_dict = {"eigentlich":"basically", 'Eins': 'one', 
           'Zwei': 'two', 'Drei': 'three', 'Vier': 
           'four', 'fünf': 'five', 'sechs': 'six', 
           'sieben': 'seven', 'acht': 'eight', 
           'neun': 'nine', 'zehn': 'ten'}
```

Finally, you need a function to call to quiz the user:

```
def quiz_me(n=20):
    quiz_base = list(my_dict.keys()) # casting as list for python 3 compatibility
    for _ in range(n):
        key = random.choice(quiz_base)
        i = raw_input(key + ': ')
        if i == my_dict[key]:
            print 'correct!'
        else:
            print 'incorrect'
```

And this is how the output would look when the function is called:

```
>>> quiz_me()
fünf: five
correct!
zehn: ten
correct!
sechs: six
correct!
eigentlich: basicly
incorrect
eigentlich:
```

Note that each are randomly chosen, the last line happened to be selected again randomly, not because I answered it incorrectly prior.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean take a random German:English word within your dictionary? If you want to you can do this:

```
import random
dictionaryName ={ '''BLAH BLAH BLAH''' } 

print random.choice(dictionaryName.keys())
```

This will print the first word of any 2 words in your dictionary so if you had this in your dictionary

```
{"ONE" : "TWO"}
```

And the random.choice() chose that it would print "ONE". Just letting you know. Sorry if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I don't know about random, but I will check it out. Thanks for posting :)